# Cross IDE development with TFS 2012

Tags: xcode, visual-studio-2012, android-studio

I'm working in a project that is structured in this way:

- Backend (Web Services): C# using Visual Studio 2012 (Windows)
- Android client: Android Studio/IntelliJ (Windows)
- iOS client: XCode (MacOSX)

The project version control is under TFS 2012, also the management with the Scrum template.
I will be using the tfs command line for the TFS commands in the Android and iOS development.

So my questions are:

- How to structure my folder tree?
- Which are the best practices to follow in this kind of project mix?
- Some of you can suggest a better approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to TFS 2013 allows you to leverage Git, which is supported by all of the IDE's you're using. If upgrading is not an option and since you're already comfortable with the commandline, then you [could also consider `git tf` to create a local git repo](http://gittf.codeplex.com/) to connect you IDE's to and the commandline to push that to TFS.

As for structure, that's a wasps nest and will attract a lot of opinions and discussion. You have multiple options and there are a lot of dependencies. Are you expecting to release all three components at the same time? Or do you want to be able to push out updates for each component separately? In the first case, one big Branch structure fits best, for the other a single branch root for each component.

For [TFVC branching guidance look to the Visual Studio ALM Rangers' Branching Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).